# How to create ParallelDo loop with n dimensions of evaluation?

Tags: functions, parallelization, procedural-programming

For example if I have n=2 i get

```
ParallelDo[something, {v[1], c[1]}, {v[2], c[2]}]
```

and if I have n=3 I get

```
ParallelDo[something, {v[1], c[1]}, {v[2], c[2]}, {v[3], c[3]}]
```

n can be any natural number, for example 10.

I use v[x] as next iteration variables and c is association of earlier defined lengths.

But I don't know how to use n parameter here as ParallelDo doesn't accept lists as input. Besides if I use 'something' in the list, it will immediately evaluate instead of doing it in the ParallelDo loop.

Could anyone help me? I would be glad! <3

Comment: It sounds more like you want `ParallelMap` but using the levelspec argument. E.g for a 3D array `ParallelMap[something, myarray, {3}]`

Answer (score 1):

[The function `Sequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) "represents a sequence of arguments to be spliced automatically into any function."  This appears to be what you want.  For example:

```
n = 5;
iterator = Sequence @@ Table[{v[m], 1, m}, {m, 1, n}]
ParallelDo[
 If[PrimeQ[Sum[v[m], {m, 1, n}]], Print[Table[v[m], {m, 1, n}]]], iterator]
```

This will print out all the sequences of the form `{v[1], v[2], ... v[n]}` that sum to a prime number, with `1 <= v[m] <= m`.

Comment: That's very useful advice, thank you! Because length of c isn't too wide for my calculations, for now I just used Tuples function to generate single large list of data for my calculation - it is memory consuming solution so not ideal but for my needs enough and it doesn't require usage of v[x] iterator.